# How abs() works for 2D vector

Tags: python, math, turtle-graphics

I can't understand how abs() function works with pos() method from Turle graphics:

```
from turtle import *
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    print(str(abs(pos()))+"\t\t"+str(pos()))
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
```

The abs() function change vector like this:

```
(3.04,34.73) >> 34.862297099063255
```

Is there any mathematical explanation of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abs(x)` returns either the absolute value for `x` if `x` is an integer or a custom value for `x` if `x` implements an `__abs__()` method.
In your case, `pos()` is returning an object of type `Vec2D`, which implements the `__abs__()` method like the following:

```
def __abs__(self):
    return (self[0]**2 + self[1]**2)**0.5
```

So the value returned by `abs(x)` is here the *length* of this vector. In this case, this makes sense also because that way you get a one-dimensional representation of this vector.

Answer (score 1):

Hey that looks to be taking the scalar quantity of the vector, I.e its taking the distance from the origin as a double. the formula for that is the Pythagorean theorem (sqrt(a^2+b^2)) hope that helps!